# segmentation fault in C programme

Tags: c, encryption, segmentation-fault

```
#include<stdio.h>

int encryption_check(char* s , char* t)
{
    printf("%s",s);
    int i=0 , diff = t[0] - s[0];

    while(s[i]!='\0' && t[i]!='\0')
    {
        if(t[i]-s[i]<=0)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else if(t[i]-s[i]!=diff)
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return diff;
}

int main()
{
    int d = 0;  
    char s[]= "abc";
    char t[]= "def";    // s=plain text and t=cipher text

    d = encryption_check(s,t);
    printf("%d",d);
    return 0;
}
```

**encryption_check()** returns the difference between ciphered and plain text.
This is giving segmentation fault for some reason.
Also I would like to know how to pass strings of random (not fixed) length to encryption_check().

Comment: regarding these kinds of code sequences: `break; return -1;`  the `return` statement(s) will NEVER be executed because the `break` statement(s) have already exited the `while()` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not getting into details of what your `encryption_check` should actually do and keep it short, your `while` loop can't terminate as your `i` never changes after being set to `0`.

On the first run, `s[0] = 'a'` and `t[0] = 'd'` so `t[0] - s[0] = 3` and so the conditions in `while` will be `true`. On the consequent runs, as you don't iterate `i`, the loop won't stop.

To fix it, just add `i++` as below:

```
while(s[i]!='\0' && t[i]!='\0') {
    if(t[i]-s[i]<=0) {
        return -1;
    } else if(t[i]-s[i]!=diff) {
        return -1;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: yeah man , my bad. Thanx!! **:)** But also tell me How to pass variable length strings to encryption_check(). @Anatolli